# How can I check if the current shell is being used from vim?

Tags: vim, shell

I am running OS X. On vim, if you do the `:sh` command, you can drop to a shell to execute commands. I constantly forget whether I am in this shell or not.

Is there any way to check if I am in the shell coming from vim?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`env | grep vim` lists environment variables that vim passes to your shell. I doubt `VIMRUNTIME` is defined if you haven't started your shell from vim.

Comment: Awesome, this worked. I simply set it up to display `{vim}` in my PS1 if `VIMRUNTIME` is defined. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I type `ps` (without any options) and see if vim is listed.

Comment: at least use pstree, if there is more than one instance of vim.

Comment: @Benoit: `ps` alone should be sufficient because by default it shows only those processes associated with the current terminal. At least that's the case on the Unix systems I use.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the command name of the shell's parent process: `ps -o comm= -p $PPID`. You could for example change your prompt to include the parent process id.

Furthermore, if you only want to change your prompt in shells that are not running directly inside a terminal emulator, you can test this by checking whether the shell's controlling terminal is the same as its parent process's. If the parent is a terminal emulator, it won't have its own terminal as a controlling terminal.

For example, if you put the following lines in your `~/.kshrc` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (pick the one appropriate for your shell), your prompt will begin with `{vim}` if the shell is running under `vim`:

```
parent_command=$(ps -o comm= -p $PPID)
parent_command=${parent_command##*/}
if [ "$(ps -o tty= -p $$)" = "$(ps -o tty= -p $PPID)" ]; then
  # Not running directly under a terminal emulator
  PS1="{$parent_command}$PS1"
fi
```

You may also be interested in some of the discussion on [How to know the “level” of shells I am in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/how-to-know-the-level-of-shells-i-am-in).

Comment: Whenever I do this, and I am in the vim shell, I get `{%cpu}` instead of {vim}. And If I'm not in vim, I get errors at login.

Comment: @Mr. Man: What I wrote should work under any POSIX-compliant OS (`-o cmd=` means not to display a header line, but getting `%cpu` means that `ps` did show a header line). However `ps` differs a lot between platforms, maybe yours isn't 100% compliant. What OS is it?

Comment: I am running Mac OS X. And, if it matters, I am using the provided Terminal.app.

Comment: @Mr. Man: My mistake, the `comm` column is standard (and documented on OSX) but `cmd` isn't. You might still need `$(ps -o comm= -p $PPID | tail -n 1)` on OSX ≤10.4.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the errors, but now when I am in the vim shell, it only shows `{}` instead of `{vim}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MacVim (http://code.google.com/p/macvim/).  Whether or not your shell came from a vim instance becomes pretty obviously since your shell is in a MacVim window and not a Terminal window.